# Foliation of a homogeneous manifold and invarience of leaves

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $M=G/H$ be a foliated homogeneous manifold, where $G$ is a connected Lie group. Let $L$ be a leaf of this foliation. Suppose that $x\in L$ and $k\in G$ be an element such that $k\cdot x\in L$. How to prove that $gkg^{-1}\cdot x\in L$ for any $g\in G$?

Comment: What's the definition of a "foliated homoogeneous manifold"?  I guess what I'm really asking is how the foliation is related to the homogeneous structure.  If there is no relationship, there are easy counterexamples:  The Hopf fibration on $G/H = SU(2)/e = S^3$  is a foliation.  If $L = S^1 \cdot e$ with $x = e\in L$, then $k = i$ meets your conditions, but $j$, a conjugate of $i$, doesn't map $x$ to something in $L$.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I should then have provided the following: $G/H$ is a Levi flat $CR$-manifold and $k\cdot x=x$. Would that make the argument correct?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that also $G$ is compact

Comment: I can make a new question if you like to add an answer for the new situation in  comments

Comment: I don't need the rep, so if you want to add it as an answer please feel free.  Also, I have no experience with Levi flat CR-manifolds, so I think I will be useless on your new question.